# How does flex-shrink factor in padding and border-box?

Tags: css, flexbox

Let's say we have a flex container with a width of 400px.

Inside this container are three flex items:

```
:nth-child(1) { flex: 0 2 300px; }   /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
:nth-child(2) { flex: 0 1 200px; }
:nth-child(3) { flex: 0 2 100px; }
```

So the total width of flex items is 600px and the free space in the container is -200px.

With help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34735515/3597276), [this article](http://chriswrightdesign.com/experiments/flexbox-adventures/), and the [flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths), I've learned the basic formula for distributing negative free space among flex items:

**Step 1**

Multiply each shrink value by its basis and add them all together:

```
:nth-child(1)  2 * 300 = 600
:nth-child(2)  1 * 200 = 200
:nth-child(3)  2 * 100 = 200
```

TOTAL = 1000

**Step 2**

Divide each item above by the total to determine the *shrink factor*:

```
:nth-child(1)  600 / 1000 = .6
:nth-child(2)  200 / 1000 = .2
:nth-child(3)  200 / 1000 = .2
```

**Step 3**

Multiply the shrink factor by the negative free space to determine the space removed from each item:

```
:nth-child(1)  .6 * -200px = -120px
:nth-child(2)  .2 * -200px =  -40px
:nth-child(3)  .2 * -200px =  -40px
```

So, the computed size of each flex item should be:

```
:nth-child(1)  300px - 120px = 180px
:nth-child(2)  200px -  40px = 160px
:nth-child(3)  100px -  40px =  60px
```

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and IE11, the numbers check out. The calculation works perfectly.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex li:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 2 300px;
  background: orange;
}

.flex li:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: chartreuse;
}

.flex li:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 2 100px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex1 flex">
  <li>180px</li>
  <li>160px</li>
  <li>60px</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/om8pzewa/3/)

---

#### The Problem

When padding is introduced, however, the shrink results are different. When padding is applied along with `box-sizing: border-box`, this results in yet another set of numbers.

[image]

What's the `flex-shrink` calculation when `padding` and `box-sizing` are involved?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.flex li:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 0 2 300px;
  background: orange;
}

.flex li:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: chartreuse;
}

.flex li:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 2 100px;
  background: aqua;
}

.flex2 li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.flex3 li {
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex1 flex">
  <li>180px</li>
  <li>160px</li>
  <li>60px</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex2 flex">
  <li>144px</li>
  <li>148px</li>
  <li>48px</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex3 flex">
  <li>175.5px</li>
  <li>160px</li>
  <li>64.4px</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/om8pzewa/5/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths) defines this as

> For every unfrozen item on the line, multiply its flex shrink factor
>   by its inner [flex base size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size), and note this as its ***scaled flex
>   shrink factor***. Find the ratio of the item’s [scaled flex shrink
>   factor](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#scaled-flex-shrink-factor) to the sum of the [scaled flex shrink factors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#scaled-flex-shrink-factor) of all
>   unfrozen items on the line. Set the item’s [target main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#target-main-size) to
>   its [flex base size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size) minus a fraction of the absolute value of the
>   [remaining free space](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#remaining-free-space) proportional to the ratio.

Simplifying, frozen flex items are those which can't or don't have to be flexed anymore. I will assume no `min-width` restrictions and non-zero flex shrink factors. This way all flex items are initially unfrozen and they all become frozen after only one iteration of the flex loop.

The inner flex base size depends on the value of [`box-sizing`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#propdef-box-sizing), defined by CSS2UI as

> - `content-box`: The specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) apply to the width and height respectively of the
>     content box of the element. The padding and border of the element are
>     laid out and drawn outside the specified width and height.
> - `border-box`: Length and percentages values for width and height (and respective min/max properties) on this element determine the
>     border box of the element. That is, any padding or border specified on
>     the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified [`width`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#propdef-width)
>     and [`height`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visudet.html#propdef-height). The content width and height are calculated by
>     subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from
>     the specified width and height properties. [...] Used values, as
>     exposed for instance through getComputedStyle(), also refer to the
>     border box.

Basically, that means that sizes (widths, flex bases) have an inner an an outer variant. The inner size includes only the content, the outer one also includes paddings and border widths. The length specified in the stylesheet will be used as the inner size in case of `box-sizing: content-box`, or as the outer one in case of `box-sizing: border-box`. The other can be calculated by adding or subtracting border and padding widths.

Neglecting lots of details, the algorithm would be something like

```js
let sumScaledShrinkFactors = 0,
    remainingFreeSpace = flexContainer.innerMainSize;
for (let item of flexItems) {
  remainingFreeSpace -= item.outerFlexBasis;
  item.scaledShrinkFactor = item.innerFlexBasis * item.flexShrinkFactor;
  sumScaledShrinkFactors += item.scaledShrinkFactor;
}
for (let item of flexItems) {
  let ratio = item.scaledShrinkFactor / sumScaledShrinkFactors;
  item.innerWidth = item.innerFlexBasis + ratio * remainingFreeSpace;
}
```

With no paddings, it's as you explain

```
                                   (width)
                                   innerW │ padd │ outerW
                                   ───────┼──────┼───────
300px * (1 + 2 / 1000px * -200px) = 180px │  0px │  180px
200px * (1 + 1 / 1000px * -200px) = 160px │  0px │  160px
100px * (1 + 2 / 1000px * -200px) =  60px │  0px │   60px
                                   ───────┼──────┼───────
                                    400px │  0px │  400px
```

With `10px` horizontal paddings, the available space is reduced by `3 * 2 * 10px = 60px`, so now it's `-260px`.

```
                                   (width)
                                   innerW │ padd │ outerW
                                   ───────┼──────┼───────
300px * (1 + 2 / 1000px * -260px) = 144px │ 20px │  164px
200px * (1 + 1 / 1000px * -260px) = 148px │ 20px │  168px
100px * (1 + 2 / 1000px * -260px) =  48px │ 20px │   68px
                                   ───────┼──────┼───────
                                    340px │ 60px │  400px
```

When you use `box-sizing: border-box`, the specified flex bases are the outer ones, so the paddings are subtracted from them to calculate the inner ones, which are `280px`, `180px`, `80px`. Then the sum of the scaled flex shrink factors becomes `2*280px + 180px + 2*80px = 900px`. The available space is like in the case with no padding, because the outer flex bases are the same. Note the `width` retrieved by `getComputedStyle` will now be the outer one, so paddings are added back at the end.

```
                                                    (width)
                                    innerW │ padd │  outerW
                                   ────────┼──────┼────────
280px * (1 + 2 / 900px * -200px) ≈ 155.6px │ 20px │ 175.6px
180px * (1 + 1 / 900px * -200px) = 140.0px │ 20px │ 160.0px
 80px * (1 + 2 / 900px * -200px) ≈  44.4px │ 20px │  64.4px
                                   ────────┼──────┼────────
                                   340.0px │ 60px │ 400.0px
```

Comment: The CSSWG just (literally just now, at the CSSWG meeting I'm in) resolved to try and change the spec to make flexing take box-sizing into account, to match the OP's intuition. We hope it's web-compatible, and will get implementations to try it out and see if it works.

Comment: @Xanthir I guess it wasn't changed after all?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Oriol's answer *(which he now have updated)*, the `padding`/`border-box` will be

```
280px * (1 + 2 / 900px * -200px) + 20px = 175.5px
180px * (1 + 1 / 900px * -200px) + 20px = 160px
 80px * (1 + 2 / 900px * -200px) + 20px = 64.4px
```

where it appears that the padding is first removed from the flex-basis and then added back again, after the actual calculation, which make *kind of* some sense as that is what happens with `padding`.

Comment: Ah, of course. I forgot to add `20px` at the end so the numbers didn't match.

Comment: @Oriol I did too for a while :) ... but the thing that caused me the most of my time was to figure out the 900px, where I finally saw the need of multiply each shrink value with its basis and then add them all again,`(2 * 280) + (1 * 180) + (2 * 80) = 900px`.