# How to calculate flex shrink when flex items have a different flex basis

Tags: flexbox

Let's say I have a simple flex container with 2 flex items where the flex items' sizes exceed the containers size - where flex-shrink will be used..like so:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  outline: 5px solid;
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 0 1 600px;
  background: salmon;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Main content here</h2>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <h2>Some side content</h2>
  </aside>
</div>
```

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/jqZweK)

In the above example: The container is 600px, the section flex-item has flex basis of 600px and the aside has flex-basis of 200px - so the negative space is 200px.

So being that both flex items have the same flex-shrink factor of 1 - I expected that both flex items would shrink by 100px with the `section` getting a width of 600px - 100px = 500px and the `aside` getting 200px - 100px = 100px

But the result was actually that the `section` shrinks by 150px to 450px and the `aside` shrinks by 50px to 150px

So then I looked at [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-shrink-factor) and I found this:

> Note: The flex shrink factor is multiplied by the flex base size when
>   distributing negative space. This distributes negative space in
>   proportion to how much the item is able to shrink, so that e.g. a
>   small item won’t shrink to zero before a larger item has been
>   noticeably reduced.

So now I understand that when calculating flex-shrink on a flex item not only is the flex shrink factor taken into account, but also the flex base size (here, defined by the flex-basis property)

The problem is that I can't seem to do the math to calculate flex-shrink.

So just to continue with the above example: say I change the shrink factor of the `section` to 2...

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  outline: 5px solid;
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 0 2 600px;
  background: salmon;
}
aside {
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Main content here</h2>
  </section>
  <aside>
    <h2>Some side content</h2>
  </aside>
</div>
```

[Codepen demo #2](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/ONQjjw)

... the result is that `section` gets a width of 428px and `aside` gets a width of 121px

Can someone explain how to calculate this?

Comment: I would use %. Like 60% and 40% or however you think the split should be

Comment: This may help you understand the calculation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B thanks, flex-shrink seems to be more complicated than flex-grow and yet there doesn't seem to be much info / blog posts about it with actual calculations....+1

Comment: @Danield, Agreed. `flex-shrink` in my experience has been more complex to sort out than `flex-grow`. That question, along with the answers from @Oriol (here and there) help clear it up. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neglecting lots of details, the algorithm is something like this

```js
let sumScaledShrinkFactors = 0,
    remainingFreeSpace = flexContainer.innerMainSize;
for (let item of flexItems) {
  remainingFreeSpace -= item.outerFlexBasis;
  item.scaledShrinkFactor = item.innerFlexBasis * item.flexShrinkFactor;
  sumScaledShrinkFactors += item.scaledShrinkFactor;
}
for (let item of flexItems) {
  let ratio = item.scaledShrinkFactor / sumScaledShrinkFactors;
  item.innerWidth = item.innerFlexBasis + ratio * remainingFreeSpace;
}
```

So the formula is like

```
flexBasis * (1 + shrinkFactor / sumScaledShrinkFactors * remainingFreeSpace)
```

First case

```
1*600px + 1*200px ─┐               width 
                   │              ───────
600px * (1 + 1 / 800px * -200px) = 450px 
200px * (1 + 1 / 800px * -200px) = 150px 
                            │     ───────
600px - (600px + 200px) ────┘      600px
```

Second case

```
2*600px + 1*200px ──┐               width 
                    │              ───────
600px * (1 + 2 / 1400px * -200px) ≈ 429px 
200px * (1 + 1 / 1400px * -200px) ≈ 171px 
                             │     ───────
600px - (600px + 200px) ─────┘      600px
```

Comment: How can we even remember this :(