# Flex items with same property values are rendering in different sizes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using Flexbox to make a responsive site (first time I've done either of those, bear in mind) and it was all going well until I realised at some point that flex items with the same properties weren't behaving the same way.

Have a look at this, I had some issues with the page in Chrome even though I ran the CSS through Autoprefixer, but that's another issue. If you have issues with this, it might be an idea to open it in Safari, which I started testing it in. You'll have to narrow the JS window to make the left-hand side visible. https://jsfiddle.net/5p7fcmxb/1/

It's ugly as sin, since I made everything different colours to differentiate them and switched everything to default fonts for the purposes of this thread. Anyway, the basic problem is that the `#headerleft`, `#blueleft` and `#footerleft` should line up perfectly, since they have the same flex properties, as shown below:

```
#headerleft {
    background-color: red;
    height: 75px;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
            order: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 2 250px;
            flex: 1 2 250px;
}

#blueleft {
    background-color: yellow;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5;
        -ms-flex-order: 4;
            order: 4;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 2 250px;
            flex: 1 2 250px;
}

#footerleft {
    background-color: red;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 8;
        -ms-flex-order: 7;
            order: 7;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1 2 250px;
            flex: 1 2 250px;
}
```

But if you expand that JSfiddle window out, you can see that they're all different widths. At first I thought since they're in separate `header`, `middle`, and `footer` divs, which are themselves children of the overall `#container` div, they might be wrapping slightly to the left of the screen for some reason. I set everything 10px from the left and they all lined up at that side, so this seems to be an issue with the growth. If I shrink the page as narrow as it will go, the `#blueleft` and `#footerleft` elements are invisble, yet the `#headerleft` div still can still be seen. You might have noticed the middle and right-hand divs don't line up either, but the answer to the problem of the left-hand divs should apply to them too.

The idea was that the text in `#headermiddle` and `#footermiddle` would line up perfectly with the `#contentbox` div, and I'm sure I remember everything lining up at different viewport sizes when I was working on this yesterday, so I'm not sure if I've done something to break it along the way.

(If you're wondering why I have three flex containers in the first place, as opposed to having one flex container with just three main columns, it's so I could get the header, content box and footer text aligning, as well as having the content box expand according to how much text is inside. I suspect there is an easier way to achieve all of that that I'm not aware of (again, I've been properly doing this for about five or six weeks now) and having those three flex containers was where I went wrong at the first step.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a `padding: 10px` in `#contentbox` (middle row) which doesn't exist in other rows.

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to `#contentbox` to factor in that extra space.

Also, just because the `flex` rule is the same for multiple elements, doesn't mean the size of each box will be the same in each row.

The `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties work by distributing free space in the container. In other words, they use the space which the content is not using. Because your content is different in each row, the available space will be different and, therefore, the size of each box can be different.

If you simply focus on the `flex-basis` component of the `flex` shorthand (and add the `box-sizing: border-box` as I mentioned above), the columns will align.

[**Revised Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5p7fcmxb/3/)

As to why your layout disappears to the right when you re-size the window smaller, bear in mind that flex items, by default, cannot be smaller than the size of their content  (regardless of any `flex-shrink` value). You'll need to override this initial setting with `min-width: 0` (see reference below).

References:

- [flex-grow not sizing flex items as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34644807/3597276)
- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)
- [How does flex-shrink factor in padding and border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276)
- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)
- [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 1):

You've set a different [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) for the columns, while specifying their `flex` property. In order to keep the items perfectly aligned, you'll have to make sure that you use the same value across separate rows.

Since you're already using `autoprefixer`, you already have access to a modern CSS processor. I would suggest that you extract the measurements into a variable that you can reuse for the specific items.