# In what situation flexbox will get a negative inner main size?

Tags: css, flexbox

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths

here is the specification about resolve-flexible-lengths,it said:

> **If using the flex shrink factor**
>
> For every unfrozen item on the line, multiply its flex shrink factor by its inner flex base size, and note this as its scaled flex shrink factor. Find the ratio of the item’s scaled flex shrink factor to the sum of the scaled flex shrink factors of all unfrozen items on the line. Set the item’s target main size to its flex base size minus a fraction of the absolute value of the remaining free space proportional to the ratio. Note this may result in a negative inner main size; it will be corrected in the next step.

In what situation will **Note this may result in a negative inner main size; it will be corrected in the next step.** happen ?

Comment: Did you keep reading? It's a sizing loop sequence.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276

Comment: I'm asking when it will happend.Not about how to solve it