# When does flex-grow switch to flex-shrink, and vice-versa?

Tags: css, flexbox

I don't understand what makes flex items switch from grow to shrink behavior? At first I thought it is the `flex-basis` value, but what if only one item has it, or none?

Also, the specs on `flex-basis` say:

> The flex-basis CSS property specifies the flex basis which is the initial main size of a flex item.

What does that mean? If I have one item with it, and the rest are default, why is it usually starts a little bigger than the value? Where does the added space come from?

Comment: Flex-basis isn't definitive. What are the other flex values (grow/shrink)?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `flex-basis` property sets the *initial main size* of the flex item, *before free space is distributed by other flex properties.*

This means that the flex item is first sized for its defined width (in `flex-direction: row`) or height (in `flex-direction: column`).

In other words, in a row-direction flex container, where `flex-basis: 100px` is equivalent to `width: 100px`, the item would have a width of 100px.

That's the initial main size.

THEN, other flex properties are applied. Namely, `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`.

If the container is wider than 100px, then `flex-grow: 1` expands the item to fill the extra space.

If the container is less than 100px, then `flex-grow: 1` is ignored and `flex-shrink: 1` reduces the size of the item according to a [flex sizing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276).

So, to answer your question:

> When does flex switch from grow to shrink?

Assuming both properties are enabled (i.e., they are not `flex-grow: 0` or `flex-shrink: 0`), the switch will occur when the sum total of `flex-basis` / `width` / `height` on flex items is no longer less or more than the length of the container.

To make this a bit more clear:

- When the sum total of `flex-basis` / `width` / `height` on flex items is no longer *more* than the length of the container, this means there is no overflow and the items don't consume all available space. `flex-grow` works.
- When the sum total of `flex-basis` / `width` / `height` on flex items is no longer *less* than the length of the container, this means there is overflow and the items must shrink to fit inside the container. `flex-shrink` works.

*From the spec:*

> ### `flex-grow`
>
> This [property] specifies the flex grow factor, which determines how much the flex item will grow relative to the rest of
>   the flex items in the flex container when ***positive free space*** is
>   distributed.
>
> ### `flex-shrink`
>
> This [property] specifies the flex shrink factor, which determines how much the flex item will shrink relative to the rest of the flex
>   items in the flex container when ***negative free space*** is distributed.
>
> ### `flex-basis`
>
> This [property] specifies the initial main size of the flex item,
>   before free space is distributed according to the flex factors.
>
> <sub>https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property</sub>

Comment: So this means grow/shrink apply separately for each item, and are not state of the container as I thought?

Comment: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` are applied individually to each item, but the first two depend on the size of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Flex items don't switch from growing to shrink. Instead think of the parameters as the way to set the minimum, maximum, and flexible width. Using `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`, you can tell your element how it should act.

The default values for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` is `0 1 auto` (defined usually within the `flex` shorthand: `flex: 0 1 auto;`). This means, by default flex containers will not fill any remaining space. Their size is determined by the content within it (mostly).

Setting a `flex-grow` value to `1` tells the element to fill the remaining space within the container row. If there are sibling elements, divide that space evenly. Setting the value to greater than 1 tells it make that element relatively larger than all other items. ([Source: W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp))

With a default value of 1 for `flex-shrink`, this means the element will shrink relative to other elements. Not have it shrink, set the value to `0`. This means once the element hits the minimum width for an element, it will not shrink any further. Otherwise it would continue to relatively shrink.

The default value for `flex-basis` is `auto`, meaning it will automatically determine the width based on the other elements around it. Quoting from W3Schools.com,

> The length of the item. Legal values: "auto", "inherit", or a number followed by "%", "px", "em" or any other length unit. [1](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)