# children overflow despite flex-shrink being set

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, overflow

Try lowering the width of the browser until the border for `.cards` hits the card the furthest to the right. Notice that that none of the cards shrink and stays inside, instead they overflow.

Why is that? I explicitly set the `flex-shrink` property to 3.

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80vw;
}
.card {
  flex-shrink: 3;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
}
#karma-card {
  background: yellow;
}
#calculator-card {
  background: blue;
}
#supervisor-card {
  background: green;
}
#team-builder-card {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div id="supervisor-card" class="card">
    Supervisor
  </div>
  <div>
    <div id="team-builder-card" class="card">
      Team Builder
    </div>
    <div id="karma-card" class="card">
      Karma
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="calculator-card" class="card">
    Calculator
  </div>
</div>
```

**Bonus question:** Now we're at it, for some reason, the `align-content: center` property doesn't work either. I expect the green and blue card to being centered vertically (because they have more space along the cross axis).

[Edit on codepen](https://codepen.io/sebastian-nielsen/pen/bGRbMdR)

Comment: Can you please clarify `green, red and blue` should be fit within 80vw width?

Answer (score 1):

In order to shrink, you need to set the initial value( flex-basis: 250px ) instead of specifying width property.

The reason your align-content is not working is align-content set the space between the multiple flex items.

As your flex-box has only one row of item( green and blue, note that red and yellow are not flex items), just use ( ailgn-items: center ) to center your green and blue.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note:

1. First, and most importantly, the red, blue and yellow cards are not flex items. Their container (`div`) does not have `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` applied, so it's not a flex container. The children, therefore, exist in standard block layout and don't accept flex properties (i.e., `flex-shrink` is ignored and `width: 250px` is respected at all times).
2. Whether you have `flex-shrink` set to `3` or `1` or nothing (it defaults to `1`) doesn't make any difference in this case.
3. This:

   ```
   .card {
     flex-shrink: 3;
     flex-grow: 0;
     flex-basis: 0;
     height: 150px;
     width: 250px;
   }
   ```

   Can be reduced to this:

   ```
   .card {
      flex: 0 3 250px;
      height: 150px;
    }
   ```
4. Lastly, with regard to your bonus question, start by addressing (1).

---

With regard to (1), learn more about the scope of flex properties here:

- [Proper use of flex properties when nesting flex containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37840646/3597276)

With regard to (2), learn more about `flex-shrink` here:

- [When does flex-grow switch to flex-shrink, and vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39960047/3597276)

With regard to (3), learn more about the `flex` property here:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex