# How do I get flex-shrink to actually shrink an item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple flex-box layout and I would like the middle item to shrink right down, but I cannot get any situation where the `flex-shrink` property works.

I've tried removing the `flex-wrap` property on the flex-container and changed the values of the flex items, but it still doesn't work?

In the code below, how do I get the middle div to shrink to a `flex-shrink` value of 10 like the code would suggest it should do?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.container {
  background-color: #666;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.item2 {
  flex: 2 10 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item3 {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <div class="item item1">
    <h1>ITEM1</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="item item2">
    <h1>ITEM2</h1>

  </div>
  <div class="item item3">
    <h1>ITEM3</h1>
    <p> - this is the third item with more content</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/rYeoza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `flex-shrink` works.

The job of `flex-shrink` is to distribute *negative free space* in the container among items. This means it will shrink items proportionally when the items would otherwise overflow the container.

But there is no overflow condition in your container.

The first column (`.item1`) is 200px in width.

Your second column (`.item2`) has no fixed width. It is set to consume free space.

Your third column (`.item3`) has no fixed width. It is also set to consume free space.

Therefore, `flex-shrink` has nothing to do. In a container with `width: 800px`, where only 200px is used, `flex-shrink` is never called into action.

You have `flex-shrink` enabled on your three columns (with values 1, 10 and 1, respectively). If you disable `flex-shrink` on all of them you'll notice that it makes no difference to the layout.

Here's your demo with `flex-shrink: 0` applied to all three times: [revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaWVqG)

For a detailed explanation of how `flex-shrink` works, see this post:

- [How does flex-shrink factor in padding and border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276)