# Flex items are shrinking below flex-basis

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been reading stack overflow questions and other blogs on what `flex-basis` is supposed to do, but I still can't fully grasp how it affects the behaviour of an element.

Here's an example with my code:

```css
.item {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .item {
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container3 {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
}

.container3 .a,
.container3 .b {
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container3">
  <div class="item a">Segmentation fault</div>
  <div class="item b">Null pointer exception</div>
  <div class="item c">hello</div>
  <div class="item d">hello</div>
</div>
```

I set `flex-basis` to 200px for items `a` and `b` but they are both shorter than `200px` width.  I was under the impression that `flex-basis` is the "initial" width of the item, meaning "min-width" of an item.  But clearly that's not true, so I don't understand what "initial" means.

What is the specific mathematical formula that calculate the width of item `a` and `b` when a pixel value is given for `flex-basis`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink).

This means that flex items are allowed to shrink in order to not overflow the container.

Once you disable this feature, flex items won't shrink below their specified `flex-basis` values.

```css
* { flex-shrink: 0; } /* NEW */

.item {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.container .item {
  height: 50px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container3 {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
}

.container3 .a,
.container3 .b {
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container container3">
  <div class="item a">Segmentation fault</div>
  <div class="item b">Null pointer exception</div>
  <div class="item c">hello</div>
  <div class="item d">hello</div>
</div>
```

> I set `flex-basis` to 200px for items `a` and `b` but they are both shorter than 200px width. I was under the impression that `flex-basis` is the "initial" width of the item, meaning "min-width" of an item. But clearly that's not true, so I don't understand what "initial" means.

Actually, it is true. `flex-basis` sets the initial length of the item. The initial width of your items is 200px, as you defined. ***Then*** `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` are applied.

> What is the specific mathematical formula that calculate the width of item `a` and `b` when a pixel value is given for `flex-basis`?

The calculations are explained here:

- [How does flex-shrink factor in padding and border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276)

Comment: As it is in my question, I see `.item.a` having a width of 156px.  Do you know what mathematical formula is used to determine that?  Why is it 156px as opposed to 152px or any other value?  I ask because I'm trying to predict the behaviour a `flex-basis` will have on an element when flex-shrink isn't specified.

Comment: See the link at the end of my answer.