# The impact of the width property used with flex-grow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please see the code below:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="child">
    <li>Monday</li>
    <li>Tuesday</li>
    <li>Wednesday</li>
    <li>Thursday</li>
    <li>Friday</li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Notice the width of 1000px.  When I load the page there are five rows as I would expect.  If I remove the `width` property, then the boxes appear on one row as expected.

Now if I add a width of 1px, then the only change is that all boxes are the same size i.e. 372.28 pixels (not 1px).  It appears to me that the behaviour is as follows:

1. If any width is added to the flex items that means they can all fit on one row then make sure all boxes are the same size.
2. If a width is added to the flex items meaning they cannot all fit on one row then honour the width.
3. If a width is not added then the boxes can be any size i.e. the Wednesday box is biggest in this case because Wednesday is the longest word.

Have I understood this correctly and why does the width effect the flex items like this?

I have done my own research and found questions like this: [What are the differences between flex-grow and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733955/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-grow-and-width).  However, I have not found an answer to my question.  I have also read about the flex grow property here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/CR-css-flexbox-1-20181119/#flex-grow-property

Comment: the width define the initial size and flexgrow will later consume any remaining free space. You should also consider the flex-shrink factor because defining a very big with will not create an overflow due to the shrink effect. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax .. it gives an easier expalantion for the algorithm than the Spec

Comment: @Temani Afif, why are all boxes the same size (372.8 pixes) if a width of 1px is specified (see point one from my post)? Thanks.

Comment: because they all start at 1px and then all will grow the same so all will have the same width. any width will giove this result unless there is no more free space and the element will start t wrap

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that `width`, `height` and `flex-basis` in a flex container represent the *initial size* of the item.

Once that size are determined, *then* `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` enter into the picture and do their work, if possible. That can change the initial size.

Now, let's break down your question into the main points:

> Notice the width of 1000px.  When I load the page there are five rows as I would expect.  If I remove the `width` property, then the boxes appear on one row as expected.

OK

---

> Now if I add a width of 1px, then the only change is that all boxes are the same size i.e. 372.28 pixels (not 1px).

Do you mean "e.g., 372.28 pixels (not 1px)", not "i.e.", because the size of the item will vary depending on the size of the viewport. In other words, the size of each item will scale as you resize the window. But this is not an essential point.

All boxes are indeed equal length. This happens because the `width` is set to `1px`.

If you were to remove the `width` rule, then the boxes would vary in length based on their content length. This is because the default `width` / `flex-basis` is `auto`.

---

> If any width is added to the flex items that means they can all fit on one row then make sure all boxes are the same size.

Not necessarily.

The `width` property doesn't always relate to items all fitting on one row. That behavior is controlled by the `flex-wrap` and `flex-direction` properties.

Also, the `width` property doesn't always relate to items all having equal length. Other factors, such as `flex-grow`, can have an impact.

---

> If a width is added to the flex items meaning they cannot all fit on one row then honour the width.

Not necessarily.

`flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-wrap` can all have an impact.

If you want the `width` /  `flex-basis` of an item to remain fixed, set both `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` to `0` (which disables those functions).

---

> If a width is not added then the boxes can be any size i.e. the Wednesday box is biggest in this case because Wednesday is the longest word.

Not necessarily.

`flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-wrap` can all have an impact.

---

More details:

- [Make flex-grow expand items based on their original size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43520932/3597276)
- [Flex items are shrinking below flex-basis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48209955/3597276)