# How to evenly distribute width between flexbox children with nested flexboxes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on some css3 for a website I'm building. I'm attempting to make a "container" class that uses flexbox to make all its children have equal width. This works properly, but when I put a "container" and a normal element inside another "container", the two children are not of equal width.

I'm not sure why this isn't working, as it works for any element that is not a container.

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
      One Sixth
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      One Sixth
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      One Sixth
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-box">
    One half
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.container > * {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}

.container > :not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/NetworkOverflow/pen/XLbdqa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you put a container inside of a container it's adding the margin so you see double the space on the right.

I would set your container to `justify-content: space-between;` which pushes content elements to the outside edges. I'm using `flex:1` instead of `flex-basis` to tell the browser that each element should take up the same amount of space.

Your CSS becomes:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > * {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 2%;
    min-width: 0;
}

.container > *:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}

/* not needed
.container > :not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 2%;
}
*/
```

---

### *Update:*

Depending on the usage, it's sometimes helpful to add "sizing" classes that force a `flex-basis` based on the number of items. Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/ydNVzJ) example.

```
.third {
  flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 2%);
}
.half {
  flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 2%);
}
```

Comment: This does not actually seem to solve the problem, though. There is still a discrepancy between a container with two content-boxes in it and a container with a container and a content-box in it. See this: https://codepen.io/NetworkOverflow/pen/NZqRgL

Comment: Are you ok adding a class to some of them? Sometimes it helps to tell the browser exactly how big you want stuff. Here's an updated [pen](https://codepen.io/graphixboy/pen/ydNVzJ)

Answer (score 1):

You're paying a price for setting all elements to `flex-basis: 100%`.

Because you're telling all elements, regardless of the number of siblings they may have, to occupy the full width of the container, you're forcing `flex-shrink` to calculate the space necessary to accommodate them all.

This involves a relatively complex flexbox algorithm, which gets even more complex when you factor in padding and `box-sizing: border-box`, both of which exist in your code.

The algorithm is explained here: [How does flex-shrink factor in padding and border-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276)

The quickest and easiest solution would be to specify the actual width of the containers.

For the row illustrating the problem (with a container, and a container within a container), instead of setting them to `flex-basis: 100%`, which triggers `flex-shrink`, set them to `flex-basis: 50%`. Now the `flex-shrink` process is avoided and you get what you want.

I added this to your code:

```
.container > .demo50 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

[revised demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJLKvK)

```css
div.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--background-color2);
  padding: 2% 10%;
}

div.banner {
  background-color: var(--scheme-color2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px rgba(23, 196, 167, 0.5);
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.content-box {
  background-color: var(--background-color1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(84, 84, 84, 1);
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container > * {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
}

.container > :not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 2%;
}

.two-thirds {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
}

.container > .demo50 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --background-color1: #707070;
  --background-color2: #424242;
  --background-color3: #afafaf;
  --scheme-color1: #20f9d5;
  --scheme-color2: #17c4a7;
  --scheme-color3: #89e5d6;
  --text-color: #e3edeb;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
      <h1>Example</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
      <p>Using 'flex-basis: 100%' seems to work perfectly well for evenly sizing and spacing elements in a row. However, when you put a .container inside a .container and attempt to do something like you see two rows below, the .container element and the
        element that follows do not space themselves at half and half width.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
      One Half
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      One Half
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container demo50">
      <div class="content-box">
        One Sixth
      </div>
      <div class="content-box">
        One Sixth
      </div>
      <div class="content-box">
        One Sixth
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-box demo50">
      One half
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
      One Third
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      Two Thirds
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      Three Thirds
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box two-thirds">
      Two Thirds
    </div>
    <div class="content-box">
      One Third
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-box">
      One Third
    </div>
    <div class="content-box two-thirds">
      Two Thirds
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem, though. I want the container class to be able to hold any number of elements and to space them equally. If I were to write it this way, I would have to write separate css for a row with 2 elements, a row with 3 elements, etc.. I do not know how many elements will be in each row, so I need to be able to accomplish this without giving specific widths.

Comment: I understand. But then you have to contend with `flex-shrink` (see the link I posted). Like I said, there's a cost to this method.

Comment: Of course, you could disable `flex-shrink`. Then your problem is solved. But a new problem arises: the elements respect their defined widths: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RzPKmG