# Border-box behavior with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border-box, box-sizing

I'm trying to create a column-based layout with specific gutter sizes using flexbox.

I would like to include the option to add a class like `col-2` to a given element that would make that element the size of 2 of the other elements in that row, for instance. `col-3` for the size of 3 elements, `col-4` for 4, etc.

I am doing this by altering the `flex` property of the element to which the `col-n` class is added.

**SCSS mixins**

```
// number of columns
$columns: 8;

// column proportions mixin
@mixin column-prop($n) {
    flex: $columns * $n;
}

.col-2 {
    @include column-prop(2);
}
.col-3 {
    @include column-prop(3);
}
.col-4 {
    @include column-prop(4);
}
...
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>flex: 8</div>
    <div>flex: 8</div>
    <div class="col-2">flex: 16</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
    <div>flex: 8</div>
    <div>flex: 8</div>
    <div>flex: 8</div>
    <div>flex: 8</div>
    <div class="col-4">flex: 32</div>
</div>
```

This works if I do not use any padding:
[image]
But if I add padding, the padding is sized *in addition,* to the content (as if its a content-box) despite my having set `box-sizing: border-box;`on all child elements.
[image]
I believe `box-sizing: border-box;` does not work for flex items.

How can I simply have the padding be included in the size of each element as if they are `boxer-box` elements?

Comment: It looks like the problem might be the `flex-shrink` component of the `flex` property you're using. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276

Answer (score -3):

Edit: CSS-grid includes support for gutters. Let me take a crack at it...

HTML

```
<div class="grid-32">
  <div>flex: 8</div>
  <div>flex: 8</div>
  <div class="col-2">flex: 16</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-32">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>

<div class="grid-64">
  <div>flex: 8</div>
  <div>flex: 8</div>
  <div>flex: 8</div>
  <div>flex: 8</div>
  <div class="col-4">flex: 32</div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
// number of columns
$columns: 8;

@mixin make-grid($n) {
  .grid-#{$n} {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat($n, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    div {
      grid-column-end: span $columns;
      background: #ccc;
      @for $i from 1 through 4 {
        &.col-#{$i} {
          grid-column-end: span $i*$columns;
          background: hsl($i * 256/$columns, 50%, 50%);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include make-grid(4*$columns);
@include make-grid(8*$columns);
```

What I learned is that, though css-grid handles the gutters perfectly, you do need to know the total columns ahead of time. If you do know, this is a good way to get what you need.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/rNaVJvR

Comment: Not sure how this is helpful. I don't see any margins in the code.

Comment: I would like the padding (inside the border) to be included in the calculation of the element width