# How exactly is the height of two divs with flex shrink and flex-basis values calculated?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have html and css as below.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle {
  flex: 0 2 20%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 0 1 80%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">top</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

The height of the container div is 200 px. flex-grow and flex-shrink values of top div are 0 and flex-basis value is 20%. So the height of top div is 20px (200 * 0.10).Everything is ok until here. How exactly does the browser then calculate the computed height of middle and bottom divs that have flex-shrink and flex-basis values?(How the remaining 180px is divided between these two divs.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I guess you have a light version than this one, right? without padding, border

Comment: A big part of that question explains the formulas asked about here, before bringing in padding and border. @TemaniAfif

Comment: @Michael_B yes but was wondering if there is another one *easier*. It's a duplicate in all the cases since it's more generic and cover more cases.

Comment: That one came to mind since it's the most detailed. None others coming to mind at the moment. @TemaniAfif